# Setting colormap limits in pandas df.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that plots both the lines, and a table. The colormap is set to `Purples_r`, which goes from purple to white. How do you limit the colormap so that the lightest color that appears is not white, but instead just a lighter purple?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
df.plot(marker='o', colormap='Purples_r', table=np.round(df.T, 2), ax=ax)
```

I've tried to follow [Setting matplotlib colorbar range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282189/setting-matplotlib-colorbar-range), however was not successful.

Of note, I'm using pandas 0.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by getting the `segmentdata` of the colormap and make a customized colormap limited to a narrower color range:

```
In [30]:

from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib import cm
D={item: cm.Purples_r._segmentdata[item][3:-3] for item in ['blue', 'green', 'red']}
#only use the middle range of color
for item in ['blue', 'green', 'red']:
    seg=np.linspace(0,1,len(D[item]))
    for i in range(len(D[item])):
        D[item][i]=(seg[i],D[item][i][1],D[item][i][2]) 
In [31]:

New_cm = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('New_cm', D)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)))
In [32]:

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
df.plot(marker='o', colormap=cm.Purples_r, ax=ax)
plt.title('Original Purples_r')
plt.savefig('1.png')
```

[image]

```
In [33]:

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
df.plot(marker='o', colormap=New_cm, ax=ax)
plt.title('Limited Purples_r')
plt.savefig('2.png')
```

[image]

Comment: This does solve the problem. Certainly requires some work. How hard would it be to save the new colormap so it could be easily called in the future?

Comment: Yes, you can totally do that and it not even that hard. Just save the code of creating new colormaps to a python script, and import that script anytime you want to use them, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696461/import-python-script-into-another

Comment: Oh, I meant saving the custom colormaps directly into matplotlib (my question was definitely ambiguous). So a simple '%pylab' would bring in all the various custom colors. I realize you could import this as another python file, but condensing the imports would make things easier.

Comment: You can modify the `matplotlib` source, but I think it is a bad idea as you will need to do it over again after each update. Since you are using `ipython`, the best way might be to store those custom colormaps in a startup script. See the last entity in the document: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html

Comment: That's actually perfect. I had never heard of startup scripts within IPython. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, until I realized matplotlib colormaps have  `_i_under` and `_i_above` attributes that you can set manually.
In my case I was using `matplotlib.cm.Blues_r` but I wanted to set 0 (which happened to be my lowest value) to another color than white.

```
cmap = matplotlib.cm.Blues_r
cmap._i_under = 0
cmap.set_under('green')
```

The code above works for me. Then you just need to pass the colormap to `pandas.plot()`.

I don't have much experience with matplotlib internal objects, but `_i_under` and `_i_above` seem to be inherited from the matplotlib color class
(see code [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/5730794685a76e4f866dc16ad88a9f638113e349/lib/matplotlib/colors.py)).

Since using the pandas plot method is sometime much cleaner than using matplotlib or pyplot, I hope this helps!