# Setting range of colorbar in the matplotlib hist2d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple hist2d in which I'd like to range the density (colorbar) between 0 to 1.

Here is my code:

```
plt.hist2d(x_values, y_values, bins=50, normed=True)
plt.colorbar(norm=colors.NoNorm)
```

How can it set the colorbar values between 0.0 to 1.0? e.g.: [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 06, 0.8, 1.0]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vmin=0, vmax=1` to the call to `plt.hist2d`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2016)

N = 10**3
x_values = (np.random.random(size=N))*15
y_values = np.random.random(size=N)
plt.hist2d(x_values, y_values, bins=50, normed=True, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(norm=mcolors.NoNorm)
plt.show()
```

The colorbar always associates itself to a single colorable artist. When no artist is supplied (as the [`mappable`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar)), the *current* colorable artist is used. In this case, it is the artist created by `plt.hist2d`. The `vmin` and `vmax` values of that artist [affect the range of values displayed by the colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15282189/190597).

[image]